# Revert local Sourcetree repo to master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I'm new to Sourcetree and have created a mess locally, with 7 ahead commits compared to the origin/master.  I want to ignore and remove everything I've done locally and start again by reverting my local repo to the origin/master as it currently stands.  How do I do this?

*Remark*:  I know the origin/master is correct since I have another machine next to me which I don't use to do commits and just did a pull from the origin/master, and the local repo is correct on this other machine.

Comment: in source tree there a reset button at top (Discard button), or if you want to go to last commit xxxxx you can do `right click` in the history of commit (the graph), and choose `reset current branch to this commit`.

Comment: It won't seem to let me reset

Comment: Note that it is `origin/master` not `master/origin`.

Answer (score 5):

You can set your current master to match the origin master by:

Check out the master branch. Double click the branch, or open the terminal and type `git checkout master`

Then reset the branch to origin master. Locate origin/master in the log, right click, click "Reset current branch to this commit" and select hard from the dialog that comes up. Or use the command `git reset --hard origin/master`